# Probability and balanced functions

Tags: probability

A function $f: \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ is said to be balanced if half of its inputs map to $0$, and the other half map to $1$ (a partition in two of the domain). If I want to test if $f$ is balanced or constant (assuming that it is one or the other), I can choose $1 \leq k \leq 2^{n-1}$ inputs say $x_1, \cdots, x_k$ and test if $f(x_1) = \cdots =f(x_k)$. Now I am wondering what is the probability of failure, i.e. that I choose $k$ inputs, and they all map to $0$, or all map to $1$, but that in fact I just chose $k$ elements in one partition of $\{0,1\}^n$.

Suppose that $f$ is a balanced function. If the $k$ inputs are different, I think the probability should be:
$\frac {1} {2} \frac {2^{n-1} -1} {2^n - 1} \cdots \frac {2^{n-1} - (k-1)} {2^n - (k-1)}$,whereas if the $k$ inputs are not necessarily distinct, then the probability is $\frac {1} {2^k}$ . Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, your ideas are correct, although you added one term too many in your first expression. It should be $$\frac{1}{2}\ldots \frac{2^{n-1} - (k-1)}{2^n}$$.

Comment: If the function is balanced then I think the probability sampling without replacement  is $2\frac {2^{n-1}} {2^{n}} \frac {2^{n-1} -1} {2^n-1} \cdots \frac {2^{n-1} - k +1} {2^n-k+1} = 2\frac{2^{n-1}! (2^n-k)!}{2^n! (2^{n-1}-k)!}$ while the probability with replacement is the larger $\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your function is balanced, there are $2^{n-1}$ inputs that map to $0$ and $2^{n-1}$ that map to $1$. The number of ways to choose $k$ distinct inputs that all map to $0$ is $\binom{2^{n-1}}{k}$, and same for the number of ways to choose $k$ distinct inputs that all map to $1$. The total number of ways to choose $k$ inputs is $\binom{2^n}{k}$, so the probability that all $k$ inputs have the same function value is:
$$\frac{\binom{2^{n-1}}{k}+\binom{2^{n-1}}{k}}{\binom{2^{n}}{k}}=\frac{2\binom{2^{n-1}}{k}}{\binom{2^{n}}{k}}.$$

If you choose $k$ inputs at random with replacement, then they each individually have probability $1/2$ to map to $0$ and $1/2 $ to map to $1$. So the probability that they all map to $0$ or they all map to $1$ is:
$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k = \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}.$$

But your test doesn't really tell you *balanced* vs constant, it just tells you not-constant vs constant (or bad luck).

Comment: I should add that the question should assume $f$ is either balanced or constant.